# Install gstreamer using cerbero

Tags: build, gstreamer

I am on ubuntu 18.04 on a x86_64 machine and I cant seem to install gstreamer using cerbero. I followed the instructions here: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/building-from-source-using-cerbero.html

All the packages were built and I created ~/.cerbero/cerbero.cb with:

```
# For Windows x86
#prefix='/c/gstreamer/1.0/x86/'

# For Windows x86_64
#prefix='/c/gstreamer/1.0/x86_64'

# For Linux
prefix='/opt/gstreamer'

# For OS X
#prefix='/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/1.0'
```

I then tried to do dpkg -i *.deb in the ~/cerbero folder where I built everything and I get some errors:

```
kevin@kevin-Enigma:~/cerbero$ sudo dpkg -i *.deb
(Reading database ... 327435 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack base-crypto_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking base-crypto (1.15.0.1-1) over (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Preparing to unpack base-crypto-dbg_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking base-crypto-dbg (1.15.0.1-1) over (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Preparing to unpack base-crypto-dev_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking base-crypto-dev (1.15.0.1-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive base-crypto-dev_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/opt/gstreamer/lib/libgmp.so', which is also in package base-crypto 1.15.0.1-1
Preparing to unpack base-system-1.0_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking base-system-1.0 (1.15.0.1-1) over (1.15.0.1-1) ...
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/zh_TW/LC_MESSAGES': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/zh_TW': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/zh_HK/LC_MESSAGES': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/zh_HK': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/zh_CN': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/vi/LC_MESSAGES': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/vi': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/uk/LC_MESSAGES': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/uk': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/ug/LC_MESSAGES': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/ug': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/tr/LC_MESSAGES': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/tr': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/th/LC_MESSAGES': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/th': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/tg/LC_MESSAGES': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/tg': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/te/LC_MESSAGES': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/te': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/ta/LC_MESSAGES': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/ta': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/sv/LC_MESSAGES': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/sv': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/sr@latin/LC_MESSAGES': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/sr@latin': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/sr/LC_MESSAGES': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/sr': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/sl/LC_MESSAGES': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/sl': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/sk/LC_MESSAGES': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/sk': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/ru': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/ro/LC_MESSAGES': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/ro': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/pt_BR': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/pt/LC_MESSAGES': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/pt': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/pl': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/pa/LC_MESSAGES': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/pa': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/or/LC_MESSAGES': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/or': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/oc/LC_MESSAGES': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/oc': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/nl/LC_MESSAGES': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/nl': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/ne/LC_MESSAGES': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/ne': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory
```

..

```
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/ar/LC_MESSAGES': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/ar': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/an/LC_MESSAGES': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale/an': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/locale': Directory not empty
Selecting previously unselected package base-system-1.0-dbg.
Preparing to unpack base-system-1.0-dbg_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking base-system-1.0-dbg (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Preparing to unpack base-system-1.0-dev_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking base-system-1.0-dev (1.15.0.1-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive base-system-1.0-dev_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/opt/gstreamer/lib/libbz2.so', which is also in package base-system-1.0 1.15.0.1-1
Preparing to unpack gstreamer-1.0_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer-1.0 (1.15.0.1-1) over (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Preparing to unpack gstreamer-1.0-capture_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer-1.0-capture (1.15.0.1-1) over (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Preparing to unpack gstreamer-1.0-capture-dbg_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer-1.0-capture-dbg (1.15.0.1-1) over (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gstreamer-1.0-capture-dev.
Preparing to unpack gstreamer-1.0-capture-dev_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer-1.0-capture-dev (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Preparing to unpack gstreamer-1.0-codecs_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer-1.0-codecs (1.15.0.1-1) over (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Preparing to unpack gstreamer-1.0-codecs-dbg_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer-1.0-codecs-dbg (1.15.0.1-1) over (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Preparing to unpack gstreamer-1.0-codecs-dev_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer-1.0-codecs-dev (1.15.0.1-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive gstreamer-1.0-codecs-dev_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/opt/gstreamer/lib/libFLAC.so', which is also in package gstreamer-1.0-codecs 1.15.0.1-1
Preparing to unpack gstreamer-1.0-codecs-gpl_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer-1.0-codecs-gpl (1.15.0.1-1) over (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Preparing to unpack gstreamer-1.0-codecs-gpl-dbg_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer-1.0-codecs-gpl-dbg (1.15.0.1-1) over (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Preparing to unpack gstreamer-1.0-codecs-gpl-dev_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer-1.0-codecs-gpl-dev (1.15.0.1-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive gstreamer-1.0-codecs-gpl-dev_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/opt/gstreamer/lib/libass.so', which is also in package gstreamer-1.0-codecs-gpl 1.15.0.1-1
Preparing to unpack gstreamer-1.0-codecs-restricted_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer-1.0-codecs-restricted (1.15.0.1-1) over (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Preparing to unpack gstreamer-1.0-codecs-restricted-dbg_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer-1.0-codecs-restricted-dbg (1.15.0.1-1) over (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Preparing to unpack gstreamer-1.0-codecs-restricted-dev_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer-1.0-codecs-restricted-dev (1.15.0.1-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive gstreamer-1.0-codecs-restricted-dev_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/opt/gstreamer/lib/liba52.so', which is also in package gstreamer-1.0-codecs-restricted 1.15.0.1-1
Preparing to unpack gstreamer-1.0-core_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer-1.0-core (1.15.0.1-1) over (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Preparing to unpack gstreamer-1.0-core-dbg_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer-1.0-core-dbg (1.15.0.1-1) over (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Preparing to unpack gstreamer-1.0-core-dev_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer-1.0-core-dev (1.15.0.1-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive gstreamer-1.0-core-dev_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/opt/gstreamer/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstcamerabin.a', which is also in package gstreamer-1.0-capture-dev 1.15.0.1-1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Selecting previously unselected package gstreamer-1.0-dev.
Preparing to unpack gstreamer-1.0-dev_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer-1.0-dev (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Preparing to unpack gstreamer-1.0-devtools_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer-1.0-devtools (1.15.0.1-1) over (1.15.0.1-1) ...
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share/gstreamer-1.0': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/share': Directory not empty
Preparing to unpack gstreamer-1.0-devtools-dbg_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer-1.0-devtools-dbg (1.15.0.1-1) over (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Preparing to unpack gstreamer-1.0-devtools-dev_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer-1.0-devtools-dev (1.15.0.1-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive gstreamer-1.0-devtools-dev_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/opt/gstreamer/lib/libgstvalidate-1.0.so', which is also in package gstreamer-1.0-devtools 1.15.0.1-1
Preparing to unpack gstreamer-1.0-dvd_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer-1.0-dvd (1.15.0.1-1) over (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Preparing to unpack gstreamer-1.0-dvd-dbg_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer-1.0-dvd-dbg (1.15.0.1-1) over (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Preparing to unpack gstreamer-1.0-dvd-dev_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer-1.0-dvd-dev (1.15.0.1-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive gstreamer-1.0-dvd-dev_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/opt/gstreamer/lib/libdvdnav.so', which is also in package gstreamer-1.0-dvd 1.15.0.1-1
Preparing to unpack gstreamer-1.0-editing_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer-1.0-editing (1.15.0.1-1) over (1.15.0.1-1) ...
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/bin': Directory not empty
Preparing to unpack gstreamer-1.0-editing-dbg_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer-1.0-editing-dbg (1.15.0.1-1) over (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Preparing to unpack gstreamer-1.0-editing-dev_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer-1.0-editing-dev (1.15.0.1-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive gstreamer-1.0-editing-dev_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/opt/gstreamer/lib/libges-1.0.so', which is also in package gstreamer-1.0-editing 1.15.0.1-1
Preparing to unpack gstreamer-1.0-effects_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer-1.0-effects (1.15.0.1-1) over (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Preparing to unpack gstreamer-1.0-effects-dbg_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer-1.0-effects-dbg (1.15.0.1-1) over (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Preparing to unpack gstreamer-1.0-effects-dev_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer-1.0-effects-dev (1.15.0.1-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive gstreamer-1.0-effects-dev_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/opt/gstreamer/lib/libSoundTouch.so', which is also in package gstreamer-1.0-effects 1.15.0.1-1
Preparing to unpack gstreamer-1.0-encoding_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer-1.0-encoding (1.15.0.1-1) over (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Preparing to unpack gstreamer-1.0-encoding-dbg_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer-1.0-encoding-dbg (1.15.0.1-1) over (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gstreamer-1.0-encoding-dev.
Preparing to unpack gstreamer-1.0-encoding-dev_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer-1.0-encoding-dev (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Preparing to unpack gstreamer-1.0-libav_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer-1.0-libav (1.15.0.1-1) over (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Preparing to unpack gstreamer-1.0-libav-dbg_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer-1.0-libav-dbg (1.15.0.1-1) over (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Preparing to unpack gstreamer-1.0-libav-dev_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer-1.0-libav-dev (1.15.0.1-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive gstreamer-1.0-libav-dev_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/opt/gstreamer/lib/libavcodec.so', which is also in package gstreamer-1.0-libav 1.15.0.1-1
Preparing to unpack gstreamer-1.0-net_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer-1.0-net (1.15.0.1-1) over (1.15.0.1-1) ...
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/lib/girepository-1.0': Directory not empty
Preparing to unpack gstreamer-1.0-net-dbg_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer-1.0-net-dbg (1.15.0.1-1) over (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Preparing to unpack gstreamer-1.0-net-dev_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer-1.0-net-dev (1.15.0.1-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive gstreamer-1.0-net-dev_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/opt/gstreamer/lib/libcrypto.so', which is also in package gstreamer-1.0-net 1.15.0.1-1
Preparing to unpack gstreamer-1.0-net-restricted_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer-1.0-net-restricted (1.15.0.1-1) over (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Preparing to unpack gstreamer-1.0-net-restricted-dbg_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer-1.0-net-restricted-dbg (1.15.0.1-1) over (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Preparing to unpack gstreamer-1.0-net-restricted-dev_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer-1.0-net-restricted-dev (1.15.0.1-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive gstreamer-1.0-net-restricted-dev_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/opt/gstreamer/lib/libmms.so', which is also in package gstreamer-1.0-net-restricted 1.15.0.1-1
Preparing to unpack gstreamer-1.0-playback_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer-1.0-playback (1.15.0.1-1) over (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Preparing to unpack gstreamer-1.0-playback-dbg_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer-1.0-playback-dbg (1.15.0.1-1) over (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gstreamer-1.0-playback-dev.
Preparing to unpack gstreamer-1.0-playback-dev_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer-1.0-playback-dev (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Preparing to unpack gstreamer-1.0-system_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer-1.0-system (1.15.0.1-1) over (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Preparing to unpack gstreamer-1.0-system-dbg_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer-1.0-system-dbg (1.15.0.1-1) over (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Preparing to unpack gstreamer-1.0-system-dev_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer-1.0-system-dev (1.15.0.1-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive gstreamer-1.0-system-dev_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/opt/gstreamer/lib/libcdda_interface.so', which is also in package gstreamer-1.0-system 1.15.0.1-1
Preparing to unpack gstreamer-1.0-visualizers_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer-1.0-visualizers (1.15.0.1-1) over (1.15.0.1-1) ...
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/lib/gstreamer-1.0': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64/lib': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist/linux_x86_64': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build/dist': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero/build': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin/cerbero': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/home/kevin': Directory not empty
Preparing to unpack gstreamer-1.0-visualizers-dbg_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer-1.0-visualizers-dbg (1.15.0.1-1) over (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Preparing to unpack gstreamer-1.0-visualizers-dev_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gstreamer-1.0-visualizers-dev (1.15.0.1-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive gstreamer-1.0-visualizers-dev_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/opt/gstreamer/lib/libvisual-0.4.so', which is also in package gstreamer-1.0-visualizers 1.15.0.1-1
Setting up base-system-1.0 (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Setting up base-system-1.0-dbg (1.15.0.1-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gstreamer-1.0-capture-dev:
 gstreamer-1.0-capture-dev depends on gstreamer-1.0-core-dev; however:
  Package gstreamer-1.0-core-dev is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package gstreamer-1.0-capture-dev (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up gstreamer-1.0-core (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Setting up gstreamer-1.0-core-dbg (1.15.0.1-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gstreamer-1.0-dev:
 gstreamer-1.0-dev depends on gstreamer-1.0-core-dev; however:
  Package gstreamer-1.0-core-dev is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package gstreamer-1.0-dev (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up gstreamer-1.0-dvd (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Setting up gstreamer-1.0-dvd-dbg (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Setting up gstreamer-1.0-effects (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Setting up gstreamer-1.0-effects-dbg (1.15.0.1-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gstreamer-1.0-encoding-dev:
 gstreamer-1.0-encoding-dev depends on gstreamer-1.0-core-dev; however:
  Package gstreamer-1.0-core-dev is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package gstreamer-1.0-encoding-dev (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up gstreamer-1.0-libav (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Setting up gstreamer-1.0-libav-dbg (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Setting up gstreamer-1.0-playback (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Setting up gstreamer-1.0-playback-dbg (1.15.0.1-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gstreamer-1.0-playback-dev:
 gstreamer-1.0-playback-dev depends on gstreamer-1.0-core-dev; however:
  Package gstreamer-1.0-core-dev is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package gstreamer-1.0-playback-dev (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up gstreamer-1.0-system (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Setting up gstreamer-1.0-system-dbg (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Setting up gstreamer-1.0-visualizers (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Setting up gstreamer-1.0-visualizers-dbg (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Setting up base-crypto (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Setting up base-crypto-dbg (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Setting up gstreamer-1.0 (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Setting up gstreamer-1.0-codecs (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Setting up gstreamer-1.0-codecs-dbg (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Setting up gstreamer-1.0-codecs-gpl (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Setting up gstreamer-1.0-codecs-gpl-dbg (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Setting up gstreamer-1.0-codecs-restricted (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Setting up gstreamer-1.0-codecs-restricted-dbg (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Setting up gstreamer-1.0-encoding (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Setting up gstreamer-1.0-encoding-dbg (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Setting up gstreamer-1.0-net (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Setting up gstreamer-1.0-net-dbg (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Setting up gstreamer-1.0-net-restricted (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Setting up gstreamer-1.0-net-restricted-dbg (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Setting up gstreamer-1.0-capture (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Setting up gstreamer-1.0-capture-dbg (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Setting up gstreamer-1.0-devtools (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Setting up gstreamer-1.0-devtools-dbg (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Setting up gstreamer-1.0-editing (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Setting up gstreamer-1.0-editing-dbg (1.15.0.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 base-crypto-dev_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb
 base-system-1.0-dev_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb
 gstreamer-1.0-codecs-dev_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb
 gstreamer-1.0-codecs-gpl-dev_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb
 gstreamer-1.0-codecs-restricted-dev_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb
 gstreamer-1.0-core-dev_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb
 gstreamer-1.0-devtools-dev_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb
 gstreamer-1.0-dvd-dev_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb
 gstreamer-1.0-editing-dev_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb
 gstreamer-1.0-effects-dev_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb
 gstreamer-1.0-libav-dev_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb
 gstreamer-1.0-net-dev_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb
 gstreamer-1.0-net-restricted-dev_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb
 gstreamer-1.0-system-dev_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb
 gstreamer-1.0-visualizers-dev_1.15.0.1-1_amd64.deb
 gstreamer-1.0-capture-dev
 gstreamer-1.0-dev
 gstreamer-1.0-encoding-dev
 gstreamer-1.0-playback-dev
```

I then run this:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gstreamer-1.0-capture-dev:
 gstreamer-1.0-capture-dev depends on gstreamer-1.0-core-dev; however:
  Package gstreamer-1.0-core-dev is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package gstreamer-1.0-capture-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gstreamer-1.0-dev:
 gstreamer-1.0-dev depends on gstreamer-1.0-core-dev; however:
  Package gstreamer-1.0-core-dev is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package gstreamer-1.0-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gstreamer-1.0-encoding-dev:
 gstreamer-1.0-encoding-dev depends on gstreamer-1.0-core-dev; however:
  Package gstreamer-1.0-core-dev is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package gstreamer-1.0-encoding-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gstreamer-1.0-playback-dev:
 gstreamer-1.0-playback-dev depends on gstreamer-1.0-core-dev; however:
  Package gstreamer-1.0-core-dev is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package gstreamer-1.0-playback-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gstreamer-1.0-capture-dev
 gstreamer-1.0-dev
 gstreamer-1.0-encoding-dev
 gstreamer-1.0-playback-dev
```

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out I didn't set the path properly. set the libraries here

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/gstreamer/lib
```

and the binary path here:

```
export PATH=/opt/gstreamer/bin:$PATH
```

apparently you are not supposed to install the debs:

> http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/troubles-with-gstreamer-installation-from-Cerbero-td4673318.html

Also if you want the plugins you need to drop to the cerberos shell and download them using git like in their example